# How do you instruct NUnit to load an assembly's dll.config file from a specific directory?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, nunit, app-config, configurationmanager

If an assembly contains an app.config file, `ConfigurationManager` will load it as long as it is in the same directory as the NUnit project that is executing through NUnit-Gui.  To illustrate consider the following folder structure.

```
+ TestFolder
    testProject.nunit
  + AssemblyAFolder
      assemblyA.dll
      assemblyA.dll.config
  + AssemblyBFolder
      assemblyB.dll
      assemblyB.dll.config
```

Both `AssemblyA` and `AssemblyB` exercise code that calls into `ConfigurationManager`.  If I run these test assemblies independently in NUnit-Gui, `ConfigurationManager` will correctly resolve the local configuration files.

However, if I load `testProject.nunit` into NUnit-Gui (which contains references to both `AssemblyA` and `AssemblyB`), `ConfigurationManager` looks for the configuration file in `TestFolder` regardless of which assembly is currently executing.

Is there a way to direct NUnit to reload the application configuration to the one present in the current assembly's directory?

Here are the contents of `testProject.nunit`:

```
<NUnitProject>
  <Settings activeconfig="Debug" />
  <Config name="Debug" binpathtype="Auto">
    <assembly path="AssemblyAFolder\assemblyA.dll" />
    <assembly path="AssemblyBFolder\assemblyB.dll" />
  </Config>
</NUnitProject>
```

Comment: Not an exact answer, but could you merge the two config files and create one for the entire test project?

Comment: Fortunately, this should work in my case since I am reading distinct config sections in each assembly.  I'm curious if there is a better or more general approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NUnit blog explained of why the config files load the way they do. Basically what they said was that NUnit lets the framework handle the config files and doesn't do any of the management.

You can also use the `testProject.config` file that would be loaded in your case, to reference the config files for each of the assemblies. Using the appSettings file attribute to add keys.

One final alternative is to use the [`configSource` element attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource(VS.85).aspx) to use the section in one of the assemblies config files.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Nunit is unable to locate the path of App.config File in our project. So we need to manually tell the Nunit where the App.config File is placed in our project (obviously on the root folder).

In my case , the project structure is as following

```
     +ProjectWEBApp//web pages
       +Modules
         +aspx pages
       +web.Config

    +projectBusinesslogic //business logic .cs files
       +Modules
         +.cs

      +ProjectTestName// a seperate Nunit test cases project
        +Modules
      +App.Config
```

the ProjectWebApp uses the references of projectBusinesslogic which contains the business logic.
the +ProjectTestName uses the reference of projectBusinesslogic to perform test on the business logic.
The problems start here, Nunit test project needs its own app.config file. it won't use web.config file as in case of projectBusinesslogic,so when you run Nunit it will prompt an error

> -Null Reference exception.......object instant not set to ...........

Solution-
When you run the Nunit GUI

1. Project->Edit  a new pop up will open
2. Properties -> General->Configuration File Name-> add your **app.config** File Name
3. File->save and close the pop-up window
4. ON Nunit Gui-File-> Reload Project

and that is the simple solution for your problem

Comment: Thanks, your steps 1 - 4 was all it took!

Answer (score 3):

The `configSource` element [solution given by MarkLawrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412235/how-do-you-instruct-nunit-to-load-an-assemblys-dll-config-file-from-a-specific-d/1416639#1416639) is what I was looking for, and works nicely.  The challenge in implementing this solution however, is to make the assembly configuration load when running tests from both an explicit NUnit project (as in [my case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412235/how-do-you-instruct-nunit-to-load-an-assemblys-dll-config-file-from-a-specific-d)), AND when running the unit tests for an assembly in isolation (no explicit project).  To accomplish this, the following modifications to my file layout were required.

```
+ TestFolder
    testProject.nunit
    testProject.config
  + AssemblyAFolder
      assemblyA.dll
      assemblyA.dll.config
      assemblyA.dll.configfragment
  + AssemblyBFolder
      assemblyB.dll
      assemblyB.dll.config
      assemblyB.dll.configfragment
```

The `configfragment` files are created to contain the assembly configuration that was once in the corresponding `config` files.  Afterwards, the `config` files are modified to contain only a `configSource` element with a relative path to the corresponding `configfragment` file.  Note that the only time that this approach doesn't work is when `assemblyA.dll` and `assemblyB.dll` both require the same configuration section, as a conflict will arise when creating `testproject.config`.

After experimenting with this approach I decided to rely on generating the assembly configuration at runtime, and remove the static configuration files all together.  Here is some code that demonstrates how to generate the configuration, and make it accessible regardless of how the assembly-under-test is loaded.

```
void WithConfigurationFile(Action method)
{
    // Create the assembly configuration.
    string settingsSection = "myConfigSectionName";
    Configuration config =
        ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    config.Sections.Add(
        settingsSection,
        new ConfigSectionType(/*config element values*/);
    config.Save();

    try
    {
        // Invoke the method with the new configuration.
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(settingsSection);
        method();
    }
    finally
    {
        // Revert the assembly configuration.
        File.Delete(config.FilePath);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(settingsSection);
    }
}
```

By using the [ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134265.aspx) overload that does not accept a path, we load the configuration from the host application's working directory, which changes depending on how you run your NUnit tests.  Also, the try/finally block guarantees that your assembly configuration will not interfere with other tests, which may or may not require such configuration.

Finally, to use within a unit test:

```
[Test]
void VerifyFunctionality
{
    WithConfigurationFile(delegate
    {
        // implement unit test and assertions here
    });
}
```

I hope this helps others who may have encountered similar issues!

Answer (score 2):

Use the configfile attribute in the Config level in your .nunit file:

```
<Config name="Debug" configfile="myconfigfilenamegoeshere.config />
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you are using NUnit and a runner within Visual Studio, you can stick your value in an App.config in your test project. Then add this line to your Post-build event:

copy /Y “$(ProjectDir)App.config” “$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName).config”

When you access the ConfigurationManager in your tests, NUnit will pass the values in your app.config to .Net in the initialize method.