# Running NUnit Tests In a C# Console App

Tags: c#, nunit

I need to run NUnit tests programmatically in a console app.  Using NUnit's nunit-console.exe is not an option.  My current code is:

```
var testRunner = new SimpleTestRunner();
var package = new TestPackage("MyTests.dll", new List<string> { ("c:\MyTests\MyTests.dll" });
testRunner.Load(package);
```

When I call Load, NUnit looks for the dll in the **current process's** directory.  So I get a FileNotFoundException for something like "c:\MyTestRunner\bin\debug\MyTests.dll".

How can I force it to look for the dll in a different directory?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how it would work with NUnit's `SimpleTestRunner()` but using the `RemoteTestRunner()` instead works fine for me:

```
TestPackage testPackage = new TestPackage(@"C:\YourProject.Tests.dll");
RemoteTestRunner remoteTestRunner = new RemoteTestRunner();
remoteTestRunner.Load(testPackage);
TestResult result = remoteTestRunner.Run(new NullListener());
```

Make sure, the `nunit.framework.dll` library is in the the folder with your test assembly.

Give the `RemoteTestRunner()` a try ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the current directory

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(@"c:\MyTestRunner\bin\debug\");
```

**Update:**

It seems this is not so simple.
I`v looked around, there is an [article](http://nunit.com/index.php?p=multiAssembly&r=2.2.10) and [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412235/how-do-you-instruct-nunit-to-load-an-assemblys-dll-config-file-from-a-specific-d) on this issue.

Hope it helps

Comment: +0: Does that actually fix the problem? of how Assembly.Load works?

Comment: In windows, dll loading is done so: current dir, system32 dir, paths directories. so it should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks, but this did not work. NUnit's Load method is still looking in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the standard nunit-console.exe runs its tests in a second app domain. This way it can set the `AppDomainSetup.ApplicationBase` property to the directory in which all the DLLs are located. It also allows the test suite to optionally have its own copy of MyTests.dll.config.

I'm not familiar with the NUnit source code, and a quick browse doesn't reveal any obvious helper classes that can set up a second app domain. However there shouldn't be anything out of the ordinary: create an `AppDomainSetup` with an altered `ApplicationBase` property; create a new `AppDomain`; create your `SimpleTestRunner` inside that app domain; and call `Load` like you're doing already.