# F# Running NUnit Tests

Tags: f#, nunit

I am looking to just run a few unit tests, I have added them them in an .fs file. I want to call them from the applications entry point as and when when I want to run them.

This the test I have written

```
namespace InvoiceApp

open System
open NUnit.Framework
open FsUnit

module Test =

let testPassed testName = printfn "Test Passed!! - %s" testName
let testFailed testName = printfn "Test Failed!! - %s" testName

    [<TestFixture>]
    type Test() = 

        [<TestCase(200,10,20)>]
        let ``When profitmarging is 10% and total is 200 expect 20 `` x y z () = 
            try
                Math.percentage x y |> should equal z
                testPassed "When profitmarging is 10% and total is 200 expect 20"
            with
            | :? NUnit.Framework.AssertionException as ex -> 
                testFailed "When profitmarging is 10% and total is 200 expect 20"
                printfn "%s" ex.Message
```

How can I call these tests from the entry point in a different .fs file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little while back I built an NUnit test runner as an F# module which should support your simple execution in a command line app scenario, see [Running TAP](http://trelford.com/blog/post/TAP.aspx).

To set it up, simply include this [F# snippet](http://fssnip.net/nD) and invoke the tests with:

```
Tap.Run typeof<InvoiceApp.Test>
```

Note: you will also need to change the test case to be a member function and use a non-generic tupled argument for either NUnit's built-in runner or the TAP runner to see it, i.e.

```
member test.``When profitmarging is 10% and total is 200 expect 20 `` (x:int,y:int,z:int) =
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `SimpleTestRunner` and `RemoteTestRunner`, ala [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1882514/1366219).