# Tests project not finding tested project dll

Tags: unit-testing, c#-4.0

I am trying to see if I can implement the recommendations listed here:

http://www.ndepend.com/Res/NDependWhiteBook_Assembly.pdf

- I have my main project set up as a commandline app.
- I have my test project referencing my cmdlnApp with copylocal = false.
- I have my main project setup to output to ..\build\debug (when debugging)
- I have my test project setup to output to ..\build\tests\

I have an app.config in my test project with the following settings:

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
            <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
                <probing privatePath="debug;debug\lib;tests;" />
                <dependentAssembly>
                        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
                    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.9.0" newVersion="2.6.9.0" />
                </dependentAssembly>
                <dependentAssembly>
                    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
                    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.9.0" newVersion="2.6.9.0" />
                </dependentAssembly>
                <dependentAssembly>
                    <assemblyIdentity name="NLog" publicKeyToken="5120e14c03d0593c" culture="neutral" />
                    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
                </dependentAssembly>
                <dependentAssembly>
                    <assemblyIdentity name="nunit.framework" publicKeyToken="96d09a1eb7f44a77" culture="neutral" />
                    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.4.14350" newVersion="2.6.4.14350" />
                </dependentAssembly>
            </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

When I try to run my unit tests I receive an error:
    System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'CmdLnApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.

I have checked and the build folder is being created, the debug folder has all the files from CmdLnApp and the build folder also has a tests folder with all the testing libraries in it.

Can anyone see what I am missing?

Comment: Does your unit tests make any use of CmdLnApp? It can't find your main console executable where it looks for it, but you've said nothing about that you actually see it in the output folder.

Comment: The CmdLnApp executable does show up in the debug folder and the tests do have tests which use a dummy class in the executable.

Comment: My understanding of the 'probing' directive in the assemblybinding was that it should instruct the CLR to search the directories listed in "privatePath" to find dependencies.  Since the debug folder is a sibling of the tests folder, I was under the impression that the CmdLnApp executable should be found.

Comment: But app.config belongs to CmdLnApp. If there is no way to execute CmdLnApp, for any reason, then content of .config file is not read, and therefore, dependency probing doesn't take place at all.

Comment: I see, is there any way to get something like dependency probing to happen during testing (using nunit)?

Comment: You shouldn't be testing .exe really. Only the DLLs need to be tested as they are libraries. Your unit test acts as .exe by invoking them. If you test .exe then it's a system test or integration test. Depending on how big your system is.

Comment: The project I am working on is tiny.  The domain and everything are in one project, which ends up having everything in the executable.  But even if this was not the case, since I am using a central build location, the test still needs to probe into subfolders to find dlls if the domain is extracted from the exe.

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb: all code must be in external DLLs. It makes it more testable. Whatever is in exe can be tested by users, UI automated test, or by invoking exe with command line parameters. All of them cumbersome and liable for failure. Correct your setup and you'll have no issues.

Comment: even if the code is in a seperate dll, how is the test runner supposed to know to probe the subfolder that it will be in unless I use 'copy-local', which is what I am trying to avoid?

Comment: Then you need to instruct your test runner to use your .config file, in which you supply probing paths. If you use NUnit, then the following link explains how to do that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412235/how-do-you-instruct-nunit-to-load-an-assemblys-dll-config-file-from-a-specific. If not, then you can Google if it's possible for your particular choice. As test run is effectively equals to bootstrapping AppDomain just enough to use reflection and discover test attributes. In order to do that test runner need to load assembly into domain first.